# Getting a singleton instance using SimpleInjector for a class which implements a generic type, not actually returning a singleton

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I've been experiencing some strange code-issues, and finally seem to have noticed that what as supposed to be acting as Singleton, is not actually a singleton.  This is a cache-class, so I am ending up having multiple-versions of the same cache.  I've written some test-code as per below, and in my eyes this should work.  Am I doing anything wrong, or have I stumbled upon a bug?

```
public class GenericClassesNotRegisteredAsSingletonTest
{
    public interface ICacheManager<T> { }

    public class SettingsData { }

    public class SettingsCache : CacheManager<SettingsData> { }

    public class CacheManager<T> : ICacheManager<T> { }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        var registration = Lifestyle.Singleton
            .CreateRegistration(typeof(SettingsCache),
                typeof(SettingsCache), container);

        container.AddRegistration(
            typeof(ICacheManager<SettingsData>), registration);

        container.Verify();

        var cache1 = container.GetInstance<SettingsCache>();
        var cache2 = container.GetInstance<SettingsCache>();

        bool sameRef = cache1 == cache2;
        Assert.That(sameRef == true);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the executable test case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made the following registration:

```cs
_container.AddRegistration(
    serviceType: typeof(ICacheManager<SettingsData>),
    registration: registration);
```

And you're doing the following resolve:

```cs
_container.GetInstance<SettingsCache>();
```

You haven't registered `SettingsCache` explicitly, but only `ICacheManager<SettingsData>`. Since `SettingsCache` is a concrete class, Simple Injector will resolve it as transient instance for you.

The solution is to either register `SettingsCache` explicitly or resolve `ICacheManager<SettingsData>` instead. You can make a second registration with using the same `Registration` instance. For instance:

```cs
_container.AddRegistration(
    serviceType: typeof(SettingsCache),
    registration: registration);
```

The [Diagnostic Services](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html) will warn you about this [this type of misconfiguration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ContainerRegisteredTypes.html).